# how to solve ffmpeg watermark "No such filter: 'movie'" AND "Failed to avformat_open_input"?

Tags: c#, windows-services, ffmpeg

i am developing a windows service, my windows service use "ffmpeg" and same time i am developing a desktop application for testing the code.

i want to import a watermark in my videos. i can do it with my desktop app. but when i run my windows service it take an error.

```
ffmpeg version N-36635-gceb0dd9 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan  9 2012 17:39:58 with gcc 4.6.2
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      51. 34.100 / 51. 34.100
  libavcodec     53. 54.100 / 53. 54.100
  libavformat    53. 29.100 / 53. 29.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 58.100 /  2. 58.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    51.  2.100 / 51.  2.100
[mpeg4 @ 01CA93A0] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\Apps\SabilVideoProcesser\WAITING_FOR_WATERMARK\Pixar - For the Birds.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Nandub v1.0rc2
  Duration: 00:03:16.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2113 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (DX50 / 0x30355844), yuv420p, 720x416 [SAR 1:1 DAR 45:26], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 32 kb/s
[buffer @ 02746A20] w:720 h:416 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:1/1 sws_param:
[movie @ 02748E00] Failed to avformat_open_input 'logo.png'
Error initializing filter 'movie' with args 'logo.png'
Error opening filters!
```

i change logo.png sometimes but it didnt work and fixed. i dont understand what is wrong?

I tried change ffmpeg.exe and i downloaded from "http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/ffmpeg/mingw32/static/" but when i run service, i got an error again. this time error is different i will crazy...

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r26400, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 18 2011 04:07:05 with gcc 4.4.2
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libgsm --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --arch=x86 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-librtmp --extra-libs='-lrtmp -lpolarssl -lws2_32 -lwinmm' --target-os=mingw32 --enable-avisynth --enable-w32threads --cross-prefix=i686-mingw32- --cc='ccache i686-mingw32-gcc' --enable-memalign-hack
  libavutil     50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0
  libavcore      0.16. 1 /  0.16. 1
  libavcodec    52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
  libavformat   52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3
  libavfilter    1.74. 0 /  1.74. 0
  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
[mpeg4 @ 003dfbd0] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
[mpeg4 @ 003dfbd0] frame skip 8

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 30000.00 (30000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\Apps\SabilVideoProcesser\WAITING_FOR_WATERMARK\Pixar - For the Birds.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Nandub v1.0rc2
  Duration: 00:03:16.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2113 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 720x416 [PAR 1:1 DAR 45:26], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 189 kb/s
[buffer @ 020d51b0] w:720 h:416 pixfmt:yuv420p
No such filter: 'movie'
Error opening filters!
```

here is the my ffmpeg params;

```
-i "C:\Apps\SabilVideoProcesser\WAITING_FOR_WATERMARK\Pixar - For the Birds.avi" -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" -vcodec libx264 -acodec ac3_fixed "C:\Apps\SabilVideoProcesser\WAITING_FOR_SPLIT\inprocess_Pixar - For the Birds.avi"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Issue #1: `Failed to avformat_open_input 'logo.png'`

You are experiencing two separate issues. The message `Failed to avformat_open_input 'logo.png'` probably indicates that ffmpeg can't find `logo.png` (or perhaps can't decode it properly). Either provide an absolute path to the file or place it in the same directory (or "folder" I believe is the Windows vernacular) as your ffmpeg binary. If the file is in the correct location then run `ffmpeg -i logo.png` to see if ffmpeg can even decode it.

### Issue #2: `No such filter: 'movie'`

The second message `No such filter: 'movie'` indicates that the ffmpeg used in this command is too old and either supports no filters or is simply too old for `movie`. Binaries from arrozcru.org are outdated. The [Zeranoe FFmpeg Builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) are kept up to date and are configured sanely. You should go ahead and get a more recent binary while your at it. Revision 36635 is already at least 3696 revisions old. Then take a look at [FFmpeg: The ultimate Video and Audio Manipulation Tool](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/) for a good overview on usage.

### Adding watermark

Anyway, you don't need the `movie` source filter to add a watermark. See the example in [How to add transparent watermark in center of a video with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/1109017)

Comment: thanks for reply,  my desktop application run success when i put logo.png to same directory with desktopapp.exe but my service app doesnt run when i put same directory with serviceapp.exe..

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue

(Error initializing filter 'movie' with args '/mnt/sdcard/MyApp/frame.png').

Using static ffmpeg library in my android app. On samsung galaxy s3 it works fine, but on the lenovo and htc 2.3.6 i had same error in ffmpeg - he coudln't find my watermark. Fixed this error by moving waterkmark in the same folder as ffmpeg (executable). So now i using next path in movie filter "...movie=frame.png..." instead of "...movie=/mnt/sdcard/MyApp/frame.png". Still don't know is it a bug or i'm just doing something wrong.