# How to modify text in a mp4 video

Tags: video, mp4

i need to change text in a video. The text now is "Select the Exchanges" and i want it to show "Select the Exchange" so i just need to delete the letter "s". I would give the letter "s" just the same color like the background then it would been done, but how can i make that.

The place in the video where this text is written is static, so it does not move. Normaly not difficult, but i need to know how.

I have at moment only Windows Movie Maker and OBS Studio for video odifications, but i dont see there a option to make what i want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless the text is an overlay, like sub titles etc, which it does not look like it is in this case, then the text is actually part of each image in your video.

Changing just a single letter will be tricky to do as you will need an exact match on colour and position.

One thing you could do is add a new image with the correct text over the existing image - if you make it very slightly bigger then the addition may not be obvious.

You can use ffmpeg (https://www.ffmpeg.org) to add an image to a video in a particular position using a command like this:

```js
ffmpeg -i inputVideo.mp4 -i yourImage.png -filter_complex "overlay=5:5" -codec:a copy outputVideo.mp4
```

See this answer for examples of placing the image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/334402