# Command for putting watermark on video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, watermark

I tried to put watermark on one video but FFmpeg command won't execute and error code is 3037. I run the same code for trimming video and video is trimmed successfully so there is no issues with `inputpath` or `outputpath` also I have `ic_watermark.png` in assets folder. I tried with image from `Drawable` but same error code.

So here is the command which I tried to run and put watermark in right corner:

`String[] cmd = new String[]{"-i", videoInputPath, "-i", imagePath, "-filter_complex", "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5", videoOutPath };`

and this is the whole method:

```
private void executeFFmepg(String inputPath, String outputPath, String customCommand){
final Command command = videoKit.createCommand()
        .overwriteOutput()
        .inputPath(inputPath)
        .outputPath(outputPath)
        .customCommand(customCommand)
        .experimentalFlag()
        .build();
 new AsyncCommandExecutor(command, this).execute(); 
 }
```

I used one library based on `FFmpeg`: https://github.com/inFullMobile/videokit-ffmpeg-android
and description says that this is basically **invoking FFmpeg main() with CLI arguments**.

This is what I get from `Log`:

```
ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
05-29 15:35:08.591 24037-24037/com.cleatchaser D/FFmpeg: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20180406_140202.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
05-29 15:35:08.596 24037-24037/com.cleatchaser D/FFmpeg:     compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2018-04-06 12:02:25
  Duration: 00:00:15.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17185 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17029 kb/s, 29.95 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
05-29 15:35:08.601 24037-24037/com.cleatchaser D/FFmpeg:     Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2018-04-06 12:02:25
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
05-29 15:35:08.606 24037-24037/com.cleatchaser D/FFmpeg:       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 123 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-06 12:02:25
05-29 15:35:08.611 24037-24037/com.cleatchaser D/FFmpeg:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
05-29 15:35:08.756 24037-24037/com.cleatchaser D/FFmpeg: Input #1, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/watermark.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 856x1324, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

I tried many answers from similar questions but none of them worked.

Is possible that error is in quotes?

I don't have experience with FFmpeg so any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks man for respond I really appreciate that. Let me try to get more informations.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I updated question. And here he provided error codes:
https://github.com/inFullMobile/videokit-ffmpeg-android/blob/master/docs/ffmpeg_return_codes.txt
I don't know what they mean but mine is: Code: 3037, line: 996 
under section: `FFMPEG_OPT.C LEAD CODE: 3`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard unfortunately I can not access to output of FFmpeg maybe because this is some compiled version. That is the path of image in assets folder `Android` and way how to access it anyway I tried your suggestion as well. Thanks for your time I really appreciate that. Thank you

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I think I got the access to real `FFmpeg` output so I updated the question with output and updated command as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that's the `ffmpeg` output. Unfortunately it appears to have been truncated so some of it is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone has the issue in future with putting watermark on video here is how you can do it. This can be done using writingminds compiled FFmpeg library:
http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

Follow the instructions how to setup `FFmpeg` into your project. After that by running this command I was able to put watermark on video:

```
        String commands[]={"-y","-i",videoInputPath,"-i", imagePath,"-filter_complex","[1:v]scale=200:200 [ovrl], [0:v][ovrl]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5:enable='between(t,"+0+","+timeInSec+")'","-codec:a","copy","-strict","-2","-c:v","libx264","-preset","ultrafast",videoOutPath};
```

`videoInputPath` - is path of video

`imagePath` - is path of an image from external storage. I tried by using image from `Drawable` but didn't find that working (not saying it's not possible)

`timeInSec` - is length of video which you can get from `MediaMetadataRetriever`:

```
    File videoFile = new File(path);
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(this, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
    String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    long timeInMillisec = Long.parseLong(time );
    timeInSec = (int) (timeInMillisec /1000);
```

`videoOutPath` - path where video is going to be saved after putting watermark

Command above will also scale watermark on `200:200` you can adjust according to your needs and put it in bottom right side.