# FFMPEG multiple steps in a batch process

Tags: video, ffmpeg, trim, cut, video-watermarking

I'm new to using ffmpeg for modifying video content, and I was looking for help creating a command to do the following:

1. Trim the first 4
2. Trim the last 4 seconds of a video
3. Add a 1 second fade to beginning *and* end
4. Include a watermark in the bottom right corner

I've been able to find examples of doing each of these individually, but am not sure--syntactically--if it's possible to do all 4 of these things in a single command.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there audio in the file too, and do you need it to be trimmed as well? Should the watermark show at all times, or should it fade too?

Comment: @llogan, audio is from video camera (not a separate recording), and ideally I would like to have a watermark that fades with the video (in and out)

Answer (score 0):

1. [Get duration](https://superuser.com/a/945604/) with `ffprobe`.
2. Run `ffmpeg`. Example if duration is 30 seconds:

   ```
   ffmpeg -ss 4 -to 26 -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1]overlay=x=W-w-10:y=H-h-10,fade=t=in:d=1,fade=t=out:d=1:st=21[v];[0:a]afade=t=in:d=1,afade=t=out:d=1:st=21[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
   ```

See [FFmpeg Filter Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) for more info and [How to add and position watermark with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/)