# Rescalling and Reposition images in FFMPEG in a video #2

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to achieve this result using Mobile-FFMPEG:
[image: Required Video Output Display]

using following command:

E/COMMAND:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -t 10 -i /storage/emulated/0/InvitationTemp/image.png -s 991x903
-loop 1 -i /storage/emulated/0/InvitationTemp/image_0.png 
-loop 1 -i /storage/emulated/0/InvitationTemp/image_1.png 
-loop 1 -i /storage/emulated/0/InvitationTemp/image_2.png 
-loop 1 -i /storage/emulated/0/InvitationTemp/image_3.png 
-loop 1 -i /storage/emulated/0/InvitationTemp/image_4.png 
-filter_complex 
    
[1]scale=eval=frame:w='min(292/2,298/2)':h='min(292/2,298/2)',rotate=a=0*PI/180:c=black@0:oh='roth(0*PI/180)':ow='rotw(0*PI/180)':bilinear=1,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[img1];  [2]scale=eval=frame:w='min(258/2,322/2)':h='min(258/2,322/2)',rotate=a=0*PI/180:c=black@0:oh='roth(0*PI/180)':ow='rotw(0*PI/180)':bilinear=1,fade=in:st=1:d=2:alpha=1[img2];
[3]scale=eval=frame:w='min(240/2,218/2)':h='min(240/2,218/2)',rotate=a=0*PI/180:c=black@0:oh='roth(0*PI/180)':ow='rotw(0*PI/180)':bilinear=1,fade=in:st=2:d=3:alpha=1[img3]; [4]scale=eval=frame:w='min(290/2,320/2)':h='min(290/2,320/2)',rotate=a=0*PI/180:c=black@0:oh='roth(0*PI/180)':ow='rotw(0*PI/180)':bilinear=1,fade=in:st=3:d=4:alpha=1[img4]; [5]scale=eval=frame:w='min(425/2,91/2)':h='min(425/2,91/2)',rotate=a=0*PI/180:c=black@0:oh='roth(0*PI/180)':ow='rotw(0*PI/180)':bilinear=1,fade=in:st=4:d=5:alpha=1[img5];
[0][img1]overlay=137:341:shortest=1:format=auto[bg1];
[bg1][img2]overlay=609:74:shortest=1:format=auto[bg2];
[bg2][img3]overlay=432:325:shortest=1:format=auto[bg3];
[bg3][img4]overlay=700:579:shortest=1:format=auto[bg4];
[bg4][img5]overlay=92:786:shortest=1:format=auto,format=yuv420p /storage/emulated/0/InvitationEventVideos/video_2021_Feb_09_09_39_38.mp4
```

But I am receiving this output... Failing to rescale and repositions propertly my png's.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIJEPIHTcio

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: Review the edited code portion for command log

Comment: 1) Need the logcat for ffmpeg process. 2) Describe what is wrong with the resulting video.

Comment: The images in the video are taking xy position (some time more or less) from what i supposed... In the image I posted in the question the couples type images are near to flowers which are part of background image. These are required to be nearer to the flowers (xy position). But after creation of video they are taking more xy then be supposed... Means Horizontal X and Vertical Y are for more then supposed.  For more you can view video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIJEPIHTcio