# Overlay and scalling issue in while creating video using mobile-ffmpeg android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using command below to create a video including gif, images and an audio file, my output is
merging all the inputs but there is a problem in scaling and overlaying images.
My frame size is 600:900 and every image overlaying factors are with in frame but every image having more then 200 approx overlay in height or width is going out of frame, behind it is scalling more as I required even with these small scales...

```
E/ffCOMMAND: 
-y -ignore_loop 0 -t 30 -i 'Gif name.gif' 
-loop 1 -i 'image_0.png' 
-loop 1 -i 'image_1.png' 
-loop 1 -i 'image_2.png' 
-i 'audio_music.mp3' 
-filter_complex 
[1]scale=eval=frame:w='214':h='118',fade=t=in:st=2:d=0,fade=t=out:st=4:d=0:alpha=1[img1];
[2]scale=eval=frame:w='203':h='99',fade=t=in:st=5:d=0,fade=t=out:st=8:d=0:alpha=1[img2];
[3]scale=eval=frame:w='213':h='49',fade=t=in:st=9:d=0,fade=t=out:st=13:d=0:alpha=1[img3];
[0][img1]overlay=195:1:shortest=1:format=auto[bg1];
[bg1][img2]overlay=7:233:shortest=1:format=auto[bg2];
[bg2][img3]overlay=250:472:shortest=1:format=auto,
scale=eval=frame:w='600':h='900',format=yuv420p[v] 

-map [v] -map 4:a -preset ultrafast videofile.mp4
```

Comment: Need to see the complete log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: I have no exception or error in this command, but there is logical issue... I want to set GIF at background with overlaying images on its front with different size and position. But with these overlaying overlay=250:472its going out of screen, 7:233 half out half in side... my full frame is 600:900 x:y respectively.