# How can one use ffmpeg to position a video exactly at a specific pixel position in jpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, pixel, video-processing, ffmpeg-php

For example,

- there is a jpeg with dimensions 1900x1000 and it has a frame (a rectangle) with pixel coordinates 490x100 and 1400x500
- a video with resolution 720p needs to be placed within this rectangle

Could you pls share the ffmpeg command to concatenate the jpeg and video? I tried `-hstack` and `-xstack` filters. But, couldn't get the video inside the rectangle.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rectangle has a size of 910x400, so you have to downscale the 1280x720 video to fit. But the aspect ratios do not match. So you need to also pad or crop the 1280x720 video to properly fit inside 910x400 if you want to preserve the aspect ratio.

Combine these answers:

- [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit into static size](https://superuser.com/q/547296/)
- [How to overlay with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/)

## Crop to fit

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=910:400:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=910:400[fg];[0][fg]overlay=x=490:y=100,format=yuv420p" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

## Pad to fit

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=910:400:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=910:400:-1:-1[fg];[0][fg]overlay=x=490:y=100,format=yuv420p" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

## Squish/stretch to fit

This will ignore the aspect ratio and will result in a distorted image.

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=910:400,setsar=1[fg];[0][fg]overlay=x=490:y=100,format=yuv420p" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks @llogan. I didn't want to crop the video and needed to scale the video only to match the dimensions of the rectangle. Your response to [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit into static size](https://superuser.com/questions/547296/resizing-videos-with-ffmpeg-avconv-to-fit-into-static-sized-player) helped addressing these..

Comment: @KrishnaChebrolu I added more examples