# Convert video to different file with time and date metadata displayed in the video

Tags: video-processing

I need to develop an application that takes in video files and converts them to an MP4, with the date and time stamp displayed in the video.  I know how to retrieve the date and time from the metadata; however, I do not know how to burn it into the video.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have no idea where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg to add text or image overlays to a video - see below example to add an image:

> ffmpeg -i inputVideo.mp4 -i yourwatermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=5:5" -codec:a copy outputVideo.mp4

See this answer for more examples of placing the watermark - i.e. top left, bottom right etc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/334402

The official ffmpeg documentation is here also - look at "filter_complex filtergraph (global)":

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: I have checked into FFMPEG.  This was exactly the solution I needed.  Thanks!